# add shapefile to a ggmap in R

Tags: r, coordinates, shapefile, ggmap

I am currently trying to plot a shapefile (representing a river) onto a googlemap plot using ggmap in R.

I get my map with:

```
map <- get_googlemap(center = c(lon = 13.40, lat = 52.50), zoom = 11, scale = 2,
                     size = c(640,480), color = "bw", maptype = "satellite")
```

I can plot the map using `ggmap(map)` but I am having troubles adding the shapefile. I am trying to do that with `+ geom_polygon()` but `ggmap` wants me to enter the coordinates as a data frame.

I used `spTranform` to transform my shapefile's coordinates, and I don't know how to get the transformed coordinates to put them into a data frame and pass them to `ggmap`. If I use `coordinates(riv)` (where 'riv' is the name of the shapefile) I get something like

```
     [,1]    [,2]
0 1483815 6898445
1 1484915 6898293
2 1485984 6898123
3 1486659 6898201
4 1487148 6898012
5 1487569 6897824
```

which is not the format I'd like to have. The dhapefile was produced with Qgis, but I can't use Qgis, to tranform the coordinates there. Any help?

Comment: If you want to draw a polygon, you need to convert the shapefile to a regular data frame. Use `fortify()` in the ggplot2 package.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems to be the coordinate system. For Googlemaps you will need EPSG3857 (see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/48952/84356)) but you also need to know what your original reference system is (once you know it, you can get the Proj string descriptor from [EPSG.io](https://epsg.io/)).

```
library(sp)
# Proj description of Marcator 3857
crs3857 = '+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs'
# Find out your coordinate system and get the proj description
original_crs = "<proj description>"
# Make sure that the CRS is correctly referenced in yor polygon
mypolygon@proj4string = CRS(original_crs)
# Convert the polygon to 3857
mypolygon3857 = spTransform(mypolygon, CRS(crs3857))
# Get the coordinates
mydata = coordinates(mypolygon3857)
names(mydata) = c("lon", "lat")
# Plot
map = get_googlemap(center = c(lon = 13.40, lat = 52.50), zoom = 11, scale = 2, size = c(640,480), color = "bw", maptype = "satellite")
ggmap(map) + geom_polygon(mydata, aes(x=lon, y=lat))
```

In your case, with made up coordinates, you can make it work like this:

```
library(sp)
library(ggmap)
map = get_googlemap(center = c(lon = 13.40, lat = 52.50), zoom = 11, scale = 2, size = c(640,480), color = "bw", maptype = "satellite")
lat = c(52.5 , 52.5, 52.55,52.55)
lon = c(13.3, 13.4, 13.4, 13.3)
mydata = data.frame(lon,lat)
ggmap(map) + geom_polygon(data=mydata, aes(x=lon, y=lat), col="red", fill=NA)
```

[image]